# How to pass list from a bean to client-side (javascript) on JSF?

Tags: java, javascript, json, jsf, jsf-2

I have a list in the bean and try to push it to the client-side on JSF. I use json array for this operation. However, I get empty message in first alert and "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input" error message for the line - var obj = JSON.parse(dates) before second alert of javascript file.

Do I use UIInput object correctly? How can I pass this list to use it in javascript file?

.xhtml (UI);

```
...
    <h:inputHidden id="specDates" binding="#{planCalendarFacade.datesUIComp}"/>                             
    <input jsfc="h:commandButton" id="slctdAction" class="hiddenBtn" action="#{planCalendarFacade.getSpecificCalendarPlans}">
        <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@none" />
    </input>
...
```

planCalendarFacade.java (bean);

```
    private UIInput datesUIComp;
    ...
    public PlanCalendarFacade() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    }
    public void getSpecificCalendarPlansFromDB(){

            List<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
            temp.add("2014-05-09");

            JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
            JsonElement jsonElement = parser.parse(temp.toString());
            JsonArray jsonArray = jsonElement.getAsJsonArray();
            for(int i = 0 ; i < jsonArray.size(); i++)
                System.out.println("Item"+i+" - >"+jsonArray.get(i));

            datesUIComp.setValue(jsonArray);
    }
    public UIInput getDatesUIComp() {
        return datesUIComp;
    }

    public void setDatesUIComp(UIInput datesUIComp) {
        this.datesUIComp = datesUIComp;
    }
```

javascript file;

```
function updateAddedDayPlns(){
    $(".addedDayPlnLst").selectable({
        stop : function() {
            $(".ui-selected", this).each(function() {
                // My form-id is "mainForm"
                document.getElementById('mainForm:slctdAction').click();
                var dates = document.getElementById('mainForm:specDates').value;
                alert(dates);
                var obj = JSON.parse(dates);
                alert(obj.get[0]);
                $('.clndr').datepick({ 
                    onSelect: datePickShow,
                    multiSelect: 999, 
                    monthsToShow: [3,2]}).datepick('setDate', arr);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

All feedbacks appreciated!

Comment: Exactly why are you using an UIInput and not just a regular value binding to a String property in your backing bean?

Comment: @Gimby, I focussed on other things in codes, that's why I missed it out. Thank u!